# Android studio showing Module is not specified

Tags: android, android-studio

I update to the new android studio,  and try to run my application, but it show errors.  Module is not specified.  I go into the run configuration ,and try to select module, there is no module to let me select.

Projects I've tried with Android Studio have no errors, but the Run dialog Module is always . Would be nice if they would fix it. You'll have to stay with Eclipse until these bugs in Studio are solved. Search and you'll find many (most?) users with the same problem and lots of different ideas that don't work.

Comment: They are not bugs, they are your own misconfiguration. However, you could elaborate on your issue, then people may help you.

Comment: Post your gradle files. The issue is there.